# How to avoid recyclerview item cast errors

Tags: android

Struggling to find a solution for a cast error i get when clicking on a itemView inside viewHolder.

ViewHolder has a constraintLayout and 3 textviews, and implements onClickListeners for the textviews, 2 of them work fine, but the one connected to constraintLayout gives exception onClick->

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams
```

Where is the correct place to cast the layoutParams in adapter or should i be using a frameLayout ?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.getTargetWidget(ConstraintLayout.java:1144)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.setChildrenConstraints(ConstraintLayout.java:1038)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.updateHierarchy(ConstraintLayout.java:803)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1561)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:260)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6459)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:849)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:21051)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2583)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1893)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1522)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7098)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
```

Comment: Please also post relevant java code from your ViewHolder

Comment: Sounds like your ConstraintLayout is inside a FrameLayout, but you're still trying to cast your ConstraintLayout's LayoutParams to `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`. Are you re-using the click listener for all three clickable views?

Comment: Yeah its just a constraint layout with 3 textviews no FrameLayout.. ViewHolder implements onClickListener, setClickListener for each textview, override onClick(View v) { if (v == txtView1) {}  if (v == txtView2) {} ... just weird that 2 of them don't have exceptions, just the one thats connected to the constraintLayout, the others are constrained to the 1st textview, so the 1st is connected to the start, top, bottom of the constraintLayout and is treated as a frame layout for some reason, 2nd is connected to the end of the 1st, 3rd to the end of the 2nd, constraintLayout height = wrap_content